# How to give the user the possibility to select a photo from the phone and show the image reduced to 100x100 pixels?

Tags: android, imageview

I' m starting on android, i want to learn to do this:

To give the user the possibility to press a button and select a photo from the phone and show the image reduced to 100x100 pixels on a ImageView from my layout. If it is possible, the image haves to be 200 KB maximum

i'm searching at google but the info i am finding is too hard for me, and the examples are not the ones i am searching for

if someone can give me the code to do this will be great, my skills are not soo good

this is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profileImageLabel" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Profile Image:"
        android:layout_marginTop="13px"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/profileImageLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:maxWidth="90px"
        android:maxHeight="90px"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, go step-by-step:

1. [How to pick an image from gallery (SD Card) for my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android)
2. [Crop and resize an image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579499/crop-and-resize-an-image-in-android)

> > *my skills are not soo good*

That's sad, but it's something that you should keep personal. No one cares if you are skilled or not; better you concentrate on improve your Googling and programming skills and that's it.

Comment: your second link doesn't help me, sorry its too hard and i dont see there where he can put the dimensions