# How to compress picture and create File from picture Uri

Tags: android

I have Uri of some image at my external storage but it is too large. I have constructor further which accepts only File like parameter. How to make picture smaller adn get File from that ?

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends on how you're displaying the picture. If you're simply going to show that picture in your layout, just size the **ImageView** element appropriately in your respective layout.xml file:

```
android:minHeight="your_value"
android:minWidth="your_value"
```

Also, don't forget to set the adjustViewBounds property as well:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

If you're looking for something a bit more robust and you're concerned about the memory used to store the entire bitmap for display, then I'd look into using the [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) class and specifically the inSampleSize field.

This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579499/crop-and-resize-an-image-in-android) also provides some background for you.